# The use of prepositions plus "which"

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

How to use "in which", "by which", "of which", "on which", and "for which"? What are the differences among those?

Are there any other combinations of preposition and the word "which"?

I have searched a lot in the Internet and I cannot found detail elaboration about them.

Comment: This has an answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/q/322836/71659

Comment: Use them the same way you'd use _of whom, by whom, for whom_ when you're talking about a person instead of a thing. Look for ["pied-piping"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299), which has to do with relative clauses; you won't get anywhere looking for explanations of random chunks of language. The construction is the important thing.